# Please help me to write a query for these questions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is **student** and the other is **class**:

The first table has the following columns id, marks, classid, studentname

the data of first table is as follow:

```
id       1       2       3       4
marks    200     250     300     298
classid    2       2      1       3
studentname Vikas  Anil    Ravil  Rahul
```

The other table has the following columns id, classname

The data of the other table is as follow:

```
id          1      2    3    4
classname   BCA    MCA  BA   BCA
```

now the question is that

1. how to get the name of student and class name having the maximum marks.
2. how to get the name of student and class name having the minimum marks.
3. how to get the name of the class having maximum students.

Pls Guys help me I'm new with MySQL.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. 
At least, you should have tried something yourself, and ideally show some **code** of what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: For each question there will be different query.

Comment: why should *we* do *your* homework?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.name, b.classname 
FROM student a 
LEFT JOIN class b 
ON a.classid = b.id 
WHERE a.marks = (SELECT MAX(marks) FROM student);

SELECT a.name, b.classname 
FROM student a LEFT JOIN class b   
ON a.classid = b.id 
WHERE a.marks = (SELECT MIN(marks) FROM student);

SELECT b.classname 
FROM student a 
LEFT JOIN class b 
ON a.classid = b.id 
ORDER BY COUNT(a.classid) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

not sure but you can try this...im just a newbie too...

Comment: There shouldn't be comas after "a" and you should add semicolon after each query. Third query doesn't seem to work as it shoult. You should edit your answer to be correct and to avoid downvoting.